# Convert ISO/Windows charsets to UTF-8 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm developing a firefox plugin and i fetch web pages to do some analysis for the user. The problem is when i try to get (XMLHttpRequest) pages that are not utf-8 encoded the string i see is messed up. For example hebrew pages with windows-1125 or Chinese pages with gb2312.

I already tried the following:

```
var uDecoder=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
uDecoder.charset="windows-1255";
alert( xhr.responseText );

var decoder=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/utf8converterservice;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIUTF8ConverterService);

alert(decoder.convertStringToUTF8(xhr.responseText,"WINDOWS-1255",true));
```

I also tried `escape/unescape/encodeURIComponent`

any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `XMLHttpRequest` has tried to decode a non-UTF-8 string using UTF-8, you've already lost. The byte sequences in the page that weren't valid UTF-8 sequences will have been mangled (typically converted to `�`, the U+FFFD replacement character). No amount of re-encoding/decoding will get them back.

Pages that specify a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=something` HTTP header should be OK. Pages that don't have a real HTTP header but do have a `<meta>` version of it won't be, because `XMLHttpRequest` doesn't know about parsing HTML so it won't see the meta. If you know in advance the charset you want, you can tell `XMLHttpRequest` and it'll use it:

```
xhr.open(...);
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=gb2312');
xhr.send();
```

(This is a currently non-standardised Mozilla extension.)

If you don't know the charset in advance, you can request the page once, hack about with the header for a `<meta>` charset, parse that out and request again with the new charset.

In theory you could get a binary response in a single request:

```
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
```

and then convert that from bytes-as-chars to UTF-8. However, `iso-8859-1` wouldn't work for this because the browser interprets that charset as *really* being Windows code page 1252.

You could maybe use another codepage that maps every byte to a character, and do a load of tedious character replacements to map every character in that codepage to the character it would have been in real-ISO-8859-1, then do the conversion. Most encodings don't map *every* byte, but Arabic (cp1256) might be a candidate for this?

Comment: thanks - working...
I guess you are write i will have to fetch non-utf-8 pages twice...

Comment: Added some ideas on avoiding the second fetch... not very nice ideas, but potentially workable.