# Decoding cp1251 to UTF-8 in javascript

Tags: javascript, cp1251

How to decode `cp-1251` to `UTF-8` in javascript?

The `cp-1251` is from a datafeed, which required to decode from js client side.

There is no way to change server side output, since it is related to a 3rd party, and due to some reason, I would not use any server side programming to convert the datafeed to become another datafeed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674411/convert-iso-windows-charsets-to-utf-8-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry, but it has no duplicate, the question from me is pure JS only, no code page, no server side programming, the datafeed is from a web socket, not using xmlHTTPRequest

Comment: You can easily reverse the function from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2711936/251311

Answer (score 2):

(Assuming that by "UTF-8" you meant the JS strings in their native encoding...)

Depending on the format your 'cp-1251' data is in and depending on the browsers you need to support, you can choose from:

- [TextDecoder.decode() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode) (decodes a sequence of octets from a typed array, like `Uint8Array`) - if you're using web sockets, you can get an ArrayBuffer out of it to decode.
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1251 operates on something it calls 'byte strings' (JS `String`s consisting of characters like `\u00XY`, where 0xXY is the encoded byte.
- build the decoding table yourself ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41451528/1026))

Note that in most cases (not something as low-level as websockets though) it might be easier to read the data in the correct encoding before it ends up as a JS string (for example, you can [force XMLHttpRequest to use a certain encoding even if the server misreports the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645170/is-there-a-cross-browser-alternative-to-the-xhr-overridemimetype-function)).